# Wordpress PHP Array - Retrieve data from an array within another array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am storing some Wordpress post data inside a PHP Array in order to output to page.

**`var1`** successfully outputs the post permalink to the array inside `["post_link"]`

**`var2`** outputs an array of further information about an image (title, url). How can I change //var2 to only output the `["url"]` data within `["ad_img"]`?

```
// var1
$posts_on_page[$current_page][get_the_id()]["post_link"] = get_permalink();

// var2
$adimgtest = get_field('ad_img'); 
$posts_on_page[$current_page][get_the_id()]["ad_img"] = $adimgtest; 

var_dump($posts_on_page);


// var_dump Response
array(1) {
  [0]=> array(1) {
        [425951]=> array(11) {

            ["post_link"] => string(50) "/welcome-message/"

            ["ad_img"]=> array(18) {

              ["title"]     => string(15) "img_placeholder"
              ["url"        => string(77) "/img_placeholder-2.jpg"          
        }
    }
}
```

I thought the following code would work but think I am going wrong somewhere:

```
$adimgtest = get_field('ad_img');
$posts_on_page[ $current_page ][ get_the_id() ]["ad_img"] = $adimgtest[0]->url;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$adimgtest = get_field('ad_img');
$posts_on_page[ $current_page ][ get_the_id() ]["ad_img"] = $adimgtest[0]url;
```